# Add a "view in JSON" local task

Tags: 8

How can I add a *Preview in JSON* local task?

My link is exactly the same of entity.node.canonical, but I have to add a query string (?_format=json). I know how to add the local task, but I don't know how to append the query string to the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure URL options in links.task.yml file. See [Url::fromUri](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromUri/8.2.x) for details.

```
your_module.export:
  title: Export
  route_name: entity.node.canonical
  options:
    query: {_format: json}
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
```